# Sending Object from Server (PHP) to client (Java) using JSON

Tags: java, php, android, json

What i want to achieve is to send an Object using JSON from PHP and recieve it also as object in Java. When ever I used the below code it gives JSON exception from java saying String cannot be converterd to JSONObject. Please I will appreciate you help. Thanks

PHP code

```
<?php

  require_once("/classes/Login.class.php");//Class that connect to the database
  $user = $_GET['ballername'];
  $pass = $_GET['ballerpassword'];
  $log = new Login($user, $pass);
  $log->connect();
  //header('Content-type: application/json');

  $correct = array('success'=> true)

  echo json_encode($log);

?>
```

JAVA Code

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
ConnectToServer connectToServer = null;
String urlstring = null;
Campusian campusian;
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

    urlstring = CampusPalURL.LOGIN_URL +"ballername=" + mUserName +"&ballerpassword="+mPassword;


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(urlstring);

    HttpResponse response;
    boolean confirmation;
    try {
        response = client.execute(getMethod);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        String state = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.e("STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT ", state);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(state);
            //JSONObject confirmation = jsonObject.getJSONObject("");
            confirmation = jsonObject.getBoolean("logged_in");
            return confirmation;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Object: ", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException ee) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("EXCEPTION: ", ee.getMessage());
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } 


    // TODO: register the new account here.
    return true;
}
```

Error in Log

```
01-07 10:54:22.689: E/Object:(1022): Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I decided to check the input received from the server displaying EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity) in the Log this is what i got. Is it right?

```
  01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <head>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <title>Untitled Document</title>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): </head>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <body>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <head>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <title>Untitled Document</title>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): </head>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): <body>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): </body>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): </html>{"logged_in":true} </body>
 01-07 11:44:37.171: E/STTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT(1380): </html>
```

Comment: Which library you use to get an object from the JSON?

Comment: I think this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android. There is a really good instruction that helped me how to get and parse your JSON response.

Comment: Can you echo the value of $log in your PHP?

Comment: I am using GSON library

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add DOCTYPE or HTML tags to the PHP output, just echo (or die) the JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

Small Session Example:

```
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $u_id; 
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE USER SET USER_SESSION ='".session_id()."' WHERE user_id=$u_id"); 
    $arr = array('Data' => null,'Code' => null); 
    $arr['Code'] = 200; 
    $arr['Data']['Session_ID'] = session_id(); 
    echo json_encode($arr); 
    exit;
```

I use [Data] for any data to return and [Code] for an error code, its very handy to parse and proof.